# SharePoint 2010 Designer Workflow on item change

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

We have a SharePoint site where there are 3 workflows that are set to start on item change. All the 3 workflows have Update statements.  Because of this these workflows are going on Round Robin.  Now that we have decided to wrap all the contents under a single workflow, I have few queries before proceeding with this.

1. What happens to the running workflows(which will become previous version once the updated WF is published)
2. In the workflow settings, there are more than 10k instances of a WF running while the list item count is less than 500. How is this possible?

Any help/guidance on this is highly appreciated!

UPDATED Reg Question 2: As a part of business, the items are being deleted through workflow. While deletion, there could be other workflows(on change WFs) running on this item. Does these WF instances becomes orphan and never gets complete so that there are 10k instances of a WF?

Comment: To answer your 1 question . It will continue to run on the existing list item unless you go an explicitly remove the instance of workflow from the list setting page . Once you remove the old instance , and update happen on list item, new updated WF will execute.

Comment: @Ravindra thanks for your answer.  So does this previous version of workflow run and get completed(if not removed)? Or does it goes to some inactive state but the status appears to be In Progress

Comment: It gets completed